# Losing part of encrypted text while using crypto module in node js

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am trying to use the in-built crypto module of node to encrypt and then decrypt some information.

It almost works, except the last few characters are lost.

For example, in the following code block, I pass "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" as an input but the final output after encryption and then decryption is "The quick brown" and the rest of the string goes missing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
let crypto = require("crypto");
let algorithm = "aes256";
let key = crypto.randomBytes(32);

const encrypt = (secret) => {
  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(secret);
  return {
    iv,
    encrypted,
  };
};

const decrypt = ({ iv, encrypted }) => {
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted);
  return decrypted.toString();
};

let text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let encrypted = encrypt(text);
let decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);

console.log(decrypted);

//Expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

//Actual output: "The quick brown"
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing cipher.final()

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const url =
  "https://jsonbox.io/box_28a26747983acfdb501b/5d9dee93e6f3c60017ce16f5";

let crypto = require("crypto");
let algorithm = "aes256";
let key = crypto.randomBytes(32);

const encrypt = (secret) => {
  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(secret, "utf8", "hex");
  encrypted += cipher.final("hex");
  return {
    iv,
    encrypted
  };
};

const decrypt = ({ iv, encrypted }) => {
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, "hex", "utf8");
  decrypted += decipher.final("utf8");
  return decrypted.toString();
};

let text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let encrypted = encrypt(text);
let decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);

console.log(decrypted);
```

`Cipher.update` writes whatever buffer has been completely filled to the variable `encrypted`, but there is still a remaining chunk that has only been partially filled. `Cipher.final` will allow you to add those last few bytes to `encrypted`

The reason cipher does this is to allow for more efficient encryption of large amount of data. If you are encrypting a large file then you may not be able to hold the entire file in memory. You therefore add some file to the cipher, grab whatever output is totally finished, write that output to the output file, and add more to the input, and so on. Essentially the encryption is done in chunks, and until you call `cipher.final()`, there will almost always be part of the next chunk sitting in memory.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but also needed `decrypted += decipher.final("utf8");` in the decrypt function before returning.

Comment: @sam thanks, I've updated the answer. For some reason it worked for me without it.